# Three.js terrain shadowing

Tags: three.js

I've done a terrain using planegeometry object. I set a vertexes' y coordinate to bump my terrain. Then I added a directional light to my scene and see that there is no shadowing of the "hills" etc.

I added also a sphere  and noticed that there is also no shadow on this terrain.

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
light.position.set(-300, 120, -200); // CHANGED
scene.add(light);
scene.add( new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light, 0.2) );
```

[Directional light with sphere above the terrain](http://jsfiddle.net/a7brv8b9/1/)

But when I replaced directional light by a spotlight I've seen shadowing on a terrain that I want to have.

```
var slight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff,1);
slight.position.set(-100,60,100);
slight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
scene.add(slight);
scene.add(new THREE.SpotLightHelper(slight, 0.5));
```

[Spotlight with terrain](http://jsfiddle.net/a7brv8b9/2/)

So the questions are:

- how can I do a light that looks like sunshine so the terrain will be not plane color but depend on light? (in future it will be a part of a real city)
- what should I do to see the objects' shadows on the terrain? (from fiddle example: sphere's shadow)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are modifying the vertices of your terrain. When you do so, you have to also modify the vertex normals. One way to do that is like so:

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

To create shadows you must enable them.

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
```

three.js r.130